# Get react-native element height before rendering?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to get element height before rendering?

My code:

```
render() {

let content =
  <View style={styles.body} onLayout={this._setMaxHeight.bind(this)}>
    {this.props.children}
  </View>;

return (
  <Animated.View style={[styles.container, {height: this.state.animation}]}>

    {this.state.expanded ? content : null}

  </Animated.View>
);}
```

But onLayout is only fired when `content` is rendered, and `this.state.expanded` is set to `true`. I need to get the size before rendering it. Is it possible?

Comment: have you try using `componentWillMount()` ?

Comment: Nope. What should write inside?